# Facebook Webhooks with pages - only want to get posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm using Facebook Webhooks with a an app subscription to a page.
I've it linked to functions in Firebase, and so far everything is running really well. However, the one snag is that its recording every comment, like and update! With a really busy facebook page thats not ideal! All I want is the latest posts sent by admins and if those posts are updated or deleted to trigger also.

Any advice?

Here is my request:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Not possible. You can not subscribe to the page’s (own) posts only - you get what you get when subscribing to `feed`, anything you don’t like you need to filter out/ignore on your end.

Comment: Thanks thats helpful! I'll just have to filter the triggers then accordingly. So when  you subscribe basically you get all feed activity, not just the post?